# Reactive WebClient GET Request with text/html response

Tags: java, spring, reactive, spring-webflux

Currently I’m having an issue with new Spring 5 WebClient and I need some help to sort it out.
The issue is:

> I request some url that returns json response with content type **text/html;charset=utf-8**.
>
> But unfortunately I’m still getting an exception:
> **org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException:
> Content type 'text/html;charset=utf-8' not supported**. So I can’t
> convert response to DTO.

For request I use following code:

```
Flux<SomeDTO> response = WebClient.create("https://someUrl")
                .get()
                .uri("/someUri").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(SomeDTO.class);

response.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Btw, it really doesn’t matter which type I point in accept header, always returning text/html. So how could I get my response converted eventually?

Comment: MyClientHttpResponseDecorator(response) - Argument is ClientHttpResponse and in the map you are getting CLientResponse. Is this working ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a service send JSON with a `"text/html"` Content-Type is rather unusual.

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. configure the Jackson decoder to decode  `"text/html"` content as well; look into the `WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies)` setup method
2. change the "Content-Type" response header on the fly

Here's a proposal for the second solution:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(request)
                .map(response -> {
                    MyClientHttpResponseDecorator decorated = new 
                        MyClientHttpResponseDecorator(response); 
                    return decorated;
                })).build();

class MyClientHttpResponseDecorator extends ClientHttpResponseDecorator {

  private final HttpHeaders httpHeaders;

  public MyClientHttpResponseDecorator(ClientHttpResponse delegate) {
    super(delegate);
    this.httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(this.getDelegate().getHeaders());
    // mutate the content-type header when necessary
  }

  @Override
  public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    return this.httpHeaders;
  }
}
```

Note that you should only use that client in that context (for this host).
I'd strongly suggest to try and fix that strange content-type returned by the server, if you can.

Comment: Second option doesn't work. `UnsupportedOperationException` trying to modify a unmodifiable map Can you elaborate on your first option?

Comment: I've updated my answer for solution 2) - you can decorate the client response to avoid that problem. I've also pointed to the right build method for changing the exchange strategies.

Comment: MyClientHttpResponseDecorator decorated = new MyClientHttpResponseDecorator(response); But it seems that the `response` isn't a ClientHttpResponse.

Comment: Second solution doesnt't work liek Q_SJ said "response" seems not to be a ClientHttpResponse.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in previous answer, you can use exchangeStrategies method,

example:

```
            Flux<SomeDTO> response = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(this::acceptedCodecs).build())
                .build()
                .get()
                .uri(builder.toUriString(), 1L)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux( // .. business logic


private void acceptedCodecs(ClientCodecConfigurer clientCodecConfigurer) {
    clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().encoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
    clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().decoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing the Mime type to use text/html here?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set the maxInMemorySize along with text/html response use:

```
  WebClient invoicesWebClient() {
    return WebClient.builder()
        .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs(this::acceptedCodecs).build())
        .build();
  }

  private void acceptedCodecs(ClientCodecConfigurer clientCodecConfigurer) {
    clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(BUFFER_SIZE_16MB);
    clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().registerWithDefaultConfig(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
    clientCodecConfigurer.customCodecs().registerWithDefaultConfig(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(new ObjectMapper(), TEXT_HTML));
  }
```