# Spring WebClient unsupported Content-Type

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

I am starting to use Spring WebClient to send requests to external services.
One of those services, not under my control, responds in Json, but has the Content-Type "text" in the response headers.

```
status: 200
server: nginx/1.12.2
date: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 01:48:23 GMT
content-type: text
```

This makes the WebClient fail with the following exception when I call either `bodyToMono(String.class)` or `toEntity(String.class)`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "text": does not contain '/'
```

I am trying to see my options here, and I see none.
I am not able to change the header on the fly (I saw this post: [Reactive WebClient GET Request with text/html response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553242/reactive-webclient-get-request-with-text-html-response) but it does not work)
I am not able to make WebClient accept a mime-type that has no /.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score -2):

As a consumer, I am able to receive a String response at my Java Client using Spring WebClient for a content type: text/javascript provided by the producer.

If you are the producer of the service that sends the content-type as text, it is recommended to have it send content type in proper format.

Eg: application/json, 
    application/pdf, 
    text/javascript